# How can we expand one column in a dataframe and match index of expanded results to index of original dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, random-forest

I have a data frame with several columns, which look like this.

```
data = [['AWS', 'Amazon Web Services', '4G,5G NR', 'RAD', 'modification'], 
        ['AWS', 'Amazon Web Services', '4G,5G NR', 'RAD', 'new equipment'],
        ['GCP', 'Google Cloud Platform', '5G NR, LG', 'RAD', 'new equipment'],
        ['GCP', 'Google Cloud Platform', '4G,5G NR', 'ANT', 'replacement']] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['project_name_one', 'project_name_two', 'technology_type', 'project_type', 'modification_type']) 
  
df 

  project_name_one       project_name_two technology_type project_type  \
0              AWS    Amazon Web Services        4G,5G NR          RAD   
1              AWS    Amazon Web Services        4G,5G NR          RAD   
2              GCP  Google Cloud Platform       5G NR, LG          RAD   
3              GCP  Google Cloud Platform        4G,5G NR          ANT   

  modification_type  
0      modification  
1     new equipment  
2     new equipment  
3       replacement
```

My question is, how can I expand the technology_type column, which has comma-separated values?  I think the technology_type has to be expanded down and I think the other columns need to be expanded as well.  I tried this:

```
df_fuze['technology_type'].str.split(",", expand=True)
```

I got some extra columns with dummy variable (0s and 1s).  Is this the normal way of doing this?  Basically, I just want to prepare the data to be fed into a `RandomForestRegressor` or `RandomForestClassifier`.  That's my end game.  I want the final result to look like this.

[image]

Comment: Please post desired output

Comment: yes thats it, just join with the original df `out = df.join(df['technology_type'].str.split(",", expand=True).add_prefix('technology_type_')).drop("technology_type",1)` or you can directly get dummies for them using `df['technology_type'].str.get_dummies(",")` if thats what you are looking for

Comment: `df.technology_type = df.technology_type.str.split(', | |,')` and then `df = df.explode('technology_type').reset_index(drop=True)`. It splits on `','`, `', '`, or `' '`.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Appreciate it!!